# Import SharePoint 2010 Excel library data in List

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to import SharePoint2010 Document library Excel data in to SharePoint2010 list.
This functionality occur when Excel is added in document Library.

What can i do?

I use import spreadsheet  option, it import the data from Excel which is on the server machine (Host machine)

So please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more details .

Import spreadsheet is available on client machine also. 
you can have a local excel file and import it to create a list.. without logging to server